# How to join results of two sql queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a project and need some help. In order to frame the question well, I have created sample data and desired result format. I have a Table with three columns. All three rows can have duplicate data but the combination of CodeA, CodeB, CodeC is Unique. I need to have a Oracle SQL query (not a stored procedure) so that I can generate comma separated data in the following format on right hand side. The values in the comma separated rows needs to be distinct. Also, the Field 1 should be in sorted order.

[image]

The query I created is here but the problem with below is only that this is not getting me **DISTINCT** values. For example, at row 1 of output set, I am getting
A1           B1,B1,B2,B3          C1,C1,C2,C2
which is what I don't want. Can anybody help me?

```
SELECT CodeA As "Field 1",
 LISTAGG(CodeB, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CodeA) AS "Field 2",
 LISTAGG(CodeC, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CodeA) AS "Field 3"
FROM Table
GROUP BY CodeA
UNION
SELECT CodeB As "Field 1",
 LISTAGG(CodeA , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CodeB) AS "Field 2",
 LISTAGG(Code3, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CodeB) AS "Field 3"
FROM Table
GROUP BY CodeB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select x.codea, x.codeb, y.codec
from
(
  select codea, listagg(codeb,',') within group (order by codeb) as codeb
  from (select distinct codea, codeb from tbl)
  group by codea
) x
join
(
  select codea, listagg(codec,',') within group (order by codec) as codec
  from (select distinct codea, codec from tbl)
  group by codea
) y
  on x.codea = y.codea
```